# Internal Server Error Administrator Backend

Tags: joomla

I get an internal server error just about any time I click on anything in the administrator side of things.   This is a fresh install.  Here is the error I keep getting.

```
Dec 15 02:12:08  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => Could not find valid value for id
    [code] => 
)


Dec 15 02:12:08  [info] $backTrace = #0 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(364): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(95): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")
#2 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/PCP/Page/PCPInfo.php(60): CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object(CRM_PCP_Page_PCPInfo), TRUE)
#3 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_PCP_Page_PCPInfo->run((Array:3), NULL)
#4 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#5 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#6 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#7 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(11): civicrm_invoke()
#8 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(392): require_once("/home/rooted/public_html/2015/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#9 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/libraries/cms/component/helper.php(372): JComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/rooted/public_html/2015/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#10 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/libraries/cms/application/site.php(191): JComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#11 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/libraries/cms/application/site.php(230): JApplicationSite->dispatch()
#12 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/libraries/cms/application/cms.php(252): JApplicationSite->doExecute()
#13 /home/rooted/public_html/2015/index.php(45): JApplicationCms->execute()
#14 {main}
```

Comment: I am using this on in a sub folder of the main directory.  http://www.rooteddurango.com/2015/  but all my paths and urls seem to be set correctly to the http://www.rooteddurango.com/2015/

Comment: Hmm.  The error seems to suggest there's a problem with a personal campaign page (PCP) - which you shouldn't have on a fresh install.  Did you load in the demo data?

Comment: It looks like it could have been do to my Php & SQL having different timezones.  Got that fixed up.  I'll update on if this fixed the problem.